# Chances of Occuring SqlException or SqliteException in android

Tags: android, sqlite, exception

Im new to android and previously was working sql. In my case Im storing multiple tables in android. And each time am checking whether previous sqlite query was success or not.But haven't caught any such exceptions unless some tablename, col_name mismatch. So my question is, should I keep all that if check or should I remove that. What's the scope of SqlException in android?

Comment: Why are you checking? What does your app do when it gets an exception?

Comment: if 1st query only fails then I shouldnt proceed further right. Im using multiple DAOs for each tables

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: I can giv u a sample code